# (rauc:350): rauc-WARNING **: 07:50:14.624: Failed getting primary slot: Failed getting primary slot: fw_printenv failed with exit code: 234

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, u-boot

I am using *yocto* to build my image, am trying to integrate **RAUC**(system update solution). **RAUC** now is installed in my image but it's not working correctly.
`rauc status gives` :

```
(rauc:350): rauc-WARNING **: 07:50:14.624: Failed getting primary slot: Failed getting primary slot: fw_printenv failed with exit code: 234

=== System Info ===
Compatible:  tx6q-1036
Variant:
Booted from: (null) (/dev/mmcblk3p2)

=== Bootloader ===
Activated: (null) ((null))

=== Slot States ===
o [rootfs.1] (/dev/mmcblk0p3, ext4, inactive)
        bootname: B
        boot status: bad

o [rootfs.0] (/dev/mmcblk0p2, ext4, inactive)
        bootname: A
        boot status: bad
```

`systemctl status rauc` gives :

```
rauc.service - Rauc Update Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rauc.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-03-23 07:49:41 UTC; 8min ago
       Docs: https://rauc.readthedocs.io
   Main PID: 292 (rauc)
     Memory: 1.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/rauc.service
             `-292 /usr/bin/rauc --mount=/run/rauc service

Mar 23 07:49:41 AMR83FA51 rauc[292]: mounting slot /dev/mmcblk0p2
Mar 23 07:49:41 AMR83FA51 rauc[292]: Failed to mount slot /dev/mmcblk0p2: Slot >
Mar 23 07:49:41 AMR83FA51 rauc[292]: Failed to resolve realpath for '/dev/mmcbl>
Mar 23 07:49:41 AMR83FA51 rauc[292]: Failed to resolve realpath for '/dev/mmcbl>
Mar 23 07:49:41 AMR83FA51 rauc[292]: rauc mark: Failed to determine slot states>
Mar 23 07:50:14 AMR83FA51 rauc[353]: Configuration file wrong or corrupted
Mar 23 07:50:14 AMR83FA51 rauc[292]: Failed getting primary slot: Failed gettin>
Mar 23 07:50:14 AMR83FA51 rauc[292]: Failed to resolve realpath for '/dev/mmcbl>
Mar 23 07:50:14 AMR83FA51 rauc[292]: Failed to resolve realpath for '/dev/mmcbl>
Mar 23 07:50:14 AMR83FA51 rauc[355]: Configuration file wrong or corrupted
```

The `/etc/fw_env.config` content is : `/boot/uboot.env 0x0000 0x20000`

I'm a beginner with **u_boot** and I don't know much about **u-boot environment**, could someone help to better understand this step and how to fix it.

Comment: Did you check your environment size from config file of u-boot? Could you share the output of **strace fw_printenv**?

Comment: I just checked and seems I have no 'CONFIG_ENV_SIZE' in the config file. You will find the **strace fw_printenv** result here : https://pastebin.com/B3xuffHj

Comment: I noticed that your fw_env file does not contain headers. Check sample fw_env files from [here](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_fw_printenv_to_modify_u-boot_environment_variables) Change your file according to examples.

Comment: Could someone help me to fix the correct fw_env files for mmc, I tried to, but still have the problem. here the fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk* https://pastebin.com/xm09ewgB.